# Node.js for Asynchronous Linux Scripting

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, asynchronous, scripting

In other programs I've written, I've enjoyed the asynchronous aspects of node.js using [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

I would like to employ this same programming style (using node.js) for Linux scripting. In other words, I'd like the ability to simultaneously execute multiple Linux commands, and then after those commands are complete, I want the node.js script to then execute another grouping of commands asynchronously and so on (without blocking).

I came across [an aritlce](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-v0-12-shell-programming-synchronous-child-process/), that shows how to perform synchronous Linux command using node.js, but I have yet to find a similar tutorial that covers the management of multiple asynchronous Linux command using node.js.

Is this currently possible? If so, could you direct me to some specific resources that could help me get started with this goal?

Comment: Although I've up-voted all answers, I'm still studying them, and I'll select one of them later today. Thanks to all!

Comment: These answers are so good, I'm going to feel guilty when I choose just one of them :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm right, but I think you are looking for `exec` and `spawn`. Please see the [related API documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation). There are examples for both command in the documentation.

## `exec` and `spawn`

`exec` is the "simple" version of `spawn`. The former is using a single callback to report back to the user when the command is completed, and only when it's completely finished/failed.

```
child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

So basically the supplied callback is only called, when *everything* that was written to stdout/stderr is available, *completely*. After the process terminates (with success or failure) only then the callback is called and users (you) can act upon it. If it failed `error` is *truthy*.

`spawn` is different, because you can listen on stdout/stderr *events*. First you "spawn" a process. The `spawn` function returns a reference to the child process.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
```

`ls` here is the child process you've spawned. It has two properties (of importance right now), `stdout` and `stderr` which are event emitters. They're emitting the `data` event. When stuff it's written on either streams the callbacks registered on the `data` event is called.

```
ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

There are other important events of course (check the documentation for the most up-to-date and relevant information of course).

```
ls.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

You would use `spawn` when you want to capture stuff on stdout for example while the process is running. A good example would be if you were spawning an ffmpeg encoding task which takes minutes to finish. You could listen on stderr (because ffmpeg writes progress information to stderr instead of stdout) to parse "progress" information.

## Going line-by-line with `carrier`

There is a nice additional library you can use together with `spawn`. [It's called carrier](https://github.com/pgte/carrier). It helps reading "lines" from the stdout/stderr of spawned processes. It's useful, because the `data` parameter passed to the callbacks doesn't necessarily contain "complete" lines separated by `\n`. `carrier` helps with that. (However, it won't help you to capture ffmpeg's progress on stderr, because there are no newlines written by ffmpeg in this case, it's only a carriage return, the line is always rewritten basically.)

You would use it like this

```
var carry = require("carrier").carry;
var child = spawn("command");   
carry(child.stdout, function(line) {
   console.log("stdout", line);
});
```

## Promises and Deferreds

If you would like to use a promise/deferred style approach then you could do something like the following [using `Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which is used by AngularJS - or at least something *very* similar (see the link for a full tutorial on promises).

`spawn` returns an `Emitter` object which is not a promise. So you have to wrap the call to spawn ([see Using Deferreds](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds)).

```
var q = require("q");
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var ls = function() {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  var ls = spawn("ls", ["-lh", "/usr"]);
  ls.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    deferred.notify({stdout: true, data: data});
  });
  ls.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
    deferred.notify({stderr: true, data: data});
  });
  ls.on("close", function(code) {
    if (code === 0) {
      deferred.resolve();
    } else {
      deferred.reject(code);
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

By executing `ls()` now a promise is returned which you would use like any other promise. When it'll get resolved completely the first callback is called. If an error occurs (the process exist with a non zero exit code) the error handler is called. While the command progresses the third callback will be called (notify callback).

```
ls().then(function() {
  console.log("child process exited successfully");
}, function(err) {
  console.log("child process exited with code " + err);
}, function(args) {
  if (args.stdout) {
    console.log("stdout: " + args.data);
  } else {
    console.log("stderr: " + args.data);
  }
});
```

When something gets written to stderr you could call reject immediately however, that is a design decision. Going back to the ffmpeg example this wouldn't do you any good, because ffmpeg spits general information to stderr. However it could work with other commands.

I think you'll get it :)

<sub>Examples are taken from nodejs's documentation, because they are well understood.</sub>

Comment: I really appreciate how your answer also addresses the monitoring of running processes (event emitters).

Comment: Your answer is so helpful. It teaches me a lot of stuff (I need to know), but forgot to ask. How would you incorporate promises-style-non-blocking-control-flow into this answer's ability to also monitor command-output?

Comment: @LonnieBest See my updated answer, this is how I would use a promise style "interface". [This is how AngularJS uses it.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! I've been playing with this and it is awesome.

Comment: @LonnieBest Glad you like it! :D Satisfied customers are the best! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

In the core node libraries, synchronous functions have `Sync` appended to the function name. They are using [child_process.execFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_command_args_options), so you should be looking for [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) for the async version of the function.

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing this naming pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend an approach combining generators and promises. Here are the prerequisites:

- Node 0.11 or higher with the `--harmony` flag, or any version of io.js (no flags required).
- A generator handler. This one is my favorite: https://www.npmjs.com/package/co
- A way to convert Node's callback-based methods into promise-returning functions. I use this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ugly-adapter

Then to do the sort of thing you want:

```
var co = require('co');
var adapt = require('ugly-adapter');
var childProcessExec = require('child_process').exec;
var exec = adapt.part(childProcessExec);

co(function*() {

  // run commands in parallel by yielding
  // a single object or array
  var result = yield {
    listing: exec('ls -l'),
    mkdirResult: exec('mkdir foo'),
    blah: exec('echo "blah blah"'),
  };

  console.log(result.blah); // "blah blah"

  // run commands in series by yielding
  // one thing at a time
  var listing = yield exec('ls -l');
  var mkdirResult = yield exec('mkdir foo2');
  var blah = yield exec('echo "blah blah"');

  console.log(blah); // "blah blah"

}).catch(function(err){

  // this handles any possible errors
  // thrown by the above
  console.error(err.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

The `yield` keyword causes the function to pause, while `co` unwraps the promise and sends the result back into your function.
**Note:** The library `co` is really just a temporary stand-in for [async/await](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait) which is coming in es7 and works essentially the same way.

Comment: I'm studying your answer right now. Seems great! I'm having an issue with this line: var exec = adapt.part(child_process.exec);   I'm getting: child_process is not defined (I'm using node.js 0.12.0).

Comment: I edited your answer slightly to make it work without errors (for me).

Comment: Woops, yep, forgot to require that module!

Comment: How would you monitor stdout and stderr, while also using the promises-style control flow you've proposed?

Comment: It depends on your goals, do you need to handle those streams one chunk at a time, or is it enough to have access to them as whole strings, after the child exits?

Comment: Greim, it was tough for me to choose another answer, cause yours was so good. Thank you; I really liked your answer.

Comment: BTW, yielding an object is such a clever by to achieve parallel execution of commands.